# Jquery ordered list load more elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have an ordered list that has 100 elements.

Is there a way i can display the content 10 by 10 with a button "Load More"

Comment: Maybe some of these will help: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/

Comment: Why do you need a plugin for this?

Comment: because i dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will get you started. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/aW2eV/

```
$('button').click(function() {

    var total = $('li').length,
        hidden = $('li:hidden').length,
        diff = (total - hidden === total) ? 0 : total - hidden,
        max = 10 + diff;

    $('li').slice(diff, max).show();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a continuously cycling version shows 10 at a time http://jsfiddle.net/reHNS/2/